# How to find out the largest element number(array size), let insertion sort beat Merge sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, mergesort, insertion-sort

from wiki page of insertion sort:

> Some divide-and-conquer algorithms such as quicksort and mergesort sort by recursively dividing the list into smaller sublists which are
>   then sorted. A useful optimization in practice for these algorithms is
>   to use insertion sort for sorting small sublists, where insertion sort
>   outperforms these more complex algorithms. The size of list for which
>   insertion sort has the advantage varies by environment and
>   implementation, but is typically between eight and twenty elements.

the quote from wiki has one reason is that, the small lists from merge sort are not worse case for insertion sort.

I want to just ignore this reason.

I knew that if the array size is small, Insertion sort O(n^2) has chance to beat Merge Sort O(n log n).

I think(not sure) this is related to the constants in T(n)

Insertion sort: T(n) = c1n^2 +c2n+c3

Merge Sort: T(n) = n log n + cn

now my question is, on the same machine, same case (worse case), how to find out the largest element number, let insertion sort beat merge sort?

Comment: if you understand the O notation, you will know that this question doesnt make sense. there is no such largest n for insertion sort beats merge sort.

Comment: @DarthVader O notation is for upper bound. However if n is small, contants are making sense too. I don't know how to evaluate those constant.

Comment: you cant evaluate those constants iff your input is predetermined. if your input is in reserve sorted, you can never beat merge sort.

Comment: @DarthVader What about if the input is of size 2? Are you suggesting that a split and merge is faster than insertion sort on a size 2 array?

Comment: @glowcoder lol :) you tell me which one is better? how many comparisons do you do?

Comment: @DarthVader Well there's a lot more involved than just comparisons. How much is a function call worth to you in terms of comparisons? What about moving values to new arrays? For large values of n, it doesn't matter... for small values of n, these little overheads take a large percentage of the time.

Comment: @glowcoder you need to understand something, arrays, functions etc is not a concern of algorithms. all you care is the number of comparisons.

Comment: @DarthVader You're funny. :) Those are not a concern of "algorithmic complexity" you're right. But it is a concern of "practical application". Every professional implementation of merge sort has a cutoff where they stop doing merge sort and start doing insertion sort because it's just faster that way in a practical world. It... just... is...

Comment: @glowcoder you are funny:) no!

Comment: @DarthVader I'm confused - are you saying you're aware of a professional implementation that doesn't have a threshold at which it decides to sort the small arrays in its "divide" step using insertion sort instead of further dividing? Quick sort does it too. It's just faster, honestly! At --that-- point function calls do matter. Consider the example of size 2 - in merge sort you do 1 comparison, 1 divide, 1 merge, 2 function calls. In insertion sort, you do 1 comparison, 0 divides, 0 merges, and 0 function calls. Pretty easy to tell which will be fastest there!

Comment: you are asking me, i m not a language designer. why dont u look at java code, java uses merge sort. c# uses quicksort. check it out. let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple:

Take a set of sample arrays to sort, and iterate over a value k where k is the cutoff point for when you switch from merge to insertion.

then go

```
for(int k = 1; k < MAX_TEST_VALUE; k++) {
    System.out.println("Results for k = " + k);
    for(int[] array : arraysToTest) {
        long then = System.currentTimeMillis();
        mergeSort(array,k); // pass in k to your merge sort so it uses that
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(now - then);
    }
}
```

For what it's worth, the `java.util.Arrays` class has this to say on the matter in its internal documentation:

```
/**
 * Tuning parameter: list size at or below which insertion sort will be
 * used in preference to mergesort or quicksort.
 */
private static final int INSERTIONSORT_THRESHOLD = 7;

/**
 * Src is the source array that starts at index 0
 * Dest is the (possibly larger) array destination with a possible offset
 * low is the index in dest to start sorting
 * high is the end index in dest to end sorting
 * off is the offset to generate corresponding low, high in src
 */
private static void mergeSort(Object[] src,
              Object[] dest,
              int low,
              int high,
              int off) {
    int length = high - low;

    // Insertion sort on smallest arrays
    if (length < INSERTIONSORT_THRESHOLD) {
        for (int i=low; i<high; i++)
            for (int j=i; j>low &&
         ((Comparable) dest[j-1]).compareTo(dest[j])>0; j--)
                swap(dest, j, j-1);
        return;
    }
```

In its primitive sequences, it also uses 7, although it doesn't use the constant value.

Comment: +1 for giving a java impl. for test the k. it would be great to get k by algorithm analysis

Comment: @Kent The developers who wrote Java's Collections framework seem to think the answer is 7. But what would Joshua Bloch know about tuning Java code? Pff...

Comment: thx for the info!  7 is my lucky number too. :D  I hope I could +2

Answer (score 1):

Insertion sort usually beats merge sort for sorted (or almost sorted) lists of any size.

So the question "How to find out the largest element number(array size), let insertion sort beat Merge sort? " is not really correct.

edit:
Just to get the downvoters of my back:
The question could rephrased as:

1. "how to determine largest array size for which, on average, insertion sort beats merge sort". This usually is measured empirically by generating sample of arrays of small size and running implementations of both algorithms on them. glowcoder does that in his answer.
2. "what is the largest array size for which insertion sort in worst case performs better than merge sort" This is something that can be approximately answered by a simple calculation as IS has to do n insertions and n*(n-1) element movements (which are insertions) in worst case , while mergesort does always n*logn cell copies from one array to another. Since it will be relatively small number it doesn't even make sense to consider it.

Comment: This doesn't begin to answer the question of why merge sort uses insertion sort internally for its smaller lists.

Comment: It's not the question he asked unless i suddenly forgot how to read.

Comment: The question is "How do you determine the cutoff in size where insertion sort gets faster than merge sort." It has nothing to do with sorted vs unsorted arrays.

Comment: No, the question is: "How to find the largest n let insertion sort beat merge sort". It's impossible to answer as there are cases when for the same array size either mergesort or insertion sort will be faster.

Comment: The question you quoted is exactly the same as mine, I just decided that grammar still meant something to me. And it's not impossible to answer - you answer for the generic case.

Comment: @soulcheck downvote is not by me, but I do mentioned "worse case" in my question. sorted/"almost" sorted =/= worse case

Comment: @Kent the problem is that "worst case" is different for each algorithm.

Comment: @soulcheck the problem is actually really simple. Consider sorting something of size 8. For merge sort, you split it into 4 and 4, which further gets split into 2 2 2 2, which if you have a really bad merge sort algorithm, you go down to 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1, then you merge back to 2 2 2 2, merge to 4 4 4 4, and merge to 8. So you've done a LOT of splitting and merging, and it might actually have been faster if you just did the `n^2` insertion sort on it... That's all he's asking here...

Comment: @glowcoder if you understand the O notation, you ll know that this question doesnt make sense. no reason for downvotes.

Comment: @DarthVader I understand O notation just fine. The complexity of merge sort is such that some of the smaller terms are dropped because in comparison to main terms they're so small they don't matter. That's how big O works. The problem here is, when you have a very small data set, those 'small' terms become much larger in comparison. See my updated answer for a little tid bit about this...

Answer (score 0):

Typically, that's done by testing with arrays of varying size. When `n == 10`, insertion sort is almost certainly faster. When `n == 100`, probably not. Test, test, test, until your results converge.

I suppose it's *possible* to determine the number strictly through analysis, but to do so you'd have to know exactly what code is generated by the compiler, include instruction timings, and take into account things like the cost of cache misses, etc. All things considered, the easiest way is to derive it empirically.

Comment: is it possible to get the size by analysis?

Comment: @Kent: as I said, it's *possible* to get the size by analysis. All you have to do is determine the values of the constants. But determining those values is exceedingly difficult. You can get an *idea* of the constant factors, but the actual numbers will vary quite a bit among processors.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so we are talking about largest array length where insertion sort beats merge sort. Yes, of course for small inputs insertion sort beats merge sort because of auxiliary space
complexity. Now talking about exact data is somewhat difficult because it requires doing experiment. And it also varies from language to language. In python once n crosses 4000, it beats insertion sort in C(For reference watch https://youtu.be/Kg4bqzAqRBM //forward to 43:00). We can calculate that length in *asymptotics* though but talking about exact data is somewhat difficult.

p.s.:

- Watch the video and most of your doubts would get cleared for sure!! (https://youtu.be/Kg4bqzAqRBM)
- Also read about using insertion sort in merge sort when sub-arrays
  become sufficiently small.(Refer book: Introduction to Algorithms by
  Cormen, Chapter 2, problem 2.1). You can easily get the pdf in google.